# DHCP Discover with no Client Identifier (Internet Radio incompatible with Netgear and Linksys routers)

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I have a Sangean DDR-63 internet radio (innards made by Frontier Silicon).  If I use my Verizon WiFi cellular modem hotspot it works fine (but that's expensive).  Connected directly to my cable modem it works fine.  With a Linksys E4200 router it does not work, either wired or wireless.  I replaced the Linksys with a Netgear N900 (WNDR4500).  Again it does not work, either wired or wireless.  It freezes on the "Connected" screen.

I believe I have narrowed down the problem.  I used Wireshark and determined that the router is not responding to the DHCP Discover request.

Here are the DHCP options in the DHCP Discover request:

Option: (t=53,l=1) DHCP Message Type= DHCP Discover
Option: (T-57,l=2) Maximum DHCP Message Size=576
Option: (t=55,l=4) Parameter Request List Value = 01031c06
   1 = Subnet Mask
   3 = Router
   28 = Broadcast address
   6 = Domain Name Server
End Option

Note that there is no Option 61 Client Identifier.

(Client MAC Address is in the request in the normal place.  Client Identifier if present would typically be the Client MAC Address.)

Do the newest wireless routers (Linksys E4200, Netgear WNDR4500, both released within the past year) REQUIRE a Client Identifier parameter in the DHCP Discover request?  Is there any way to tell the Netgear router NOT to require it?

Comment: Just double checking, but do your computers connect and access the Internet when connected to the routers?

Comment: All the computers do, and the iPhone and the iPad.